# Black Screen for Message Dialog in JOptionPane (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

So I am writing my first gui code today following a tutorial for Eclipse's WindowBuilder. The code is pretty simple : create a button that would generate a dialog message. Here's the code generated through the windowbuilder :

```
private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Project1 window = new Project1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Project1() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 204, 51));
    frame.getContentPane().setForeground(SystemColor.textHighlight);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnWelcome = new JButton("Welcome");

    btnWelcome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi !");
        }
    });

    btnWelcome.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnWelcome.setForeground(Color.RED);
    btnWelcome.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 11));

    btnWelcome.setBounds(125, 95, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnWelcome);
}
```

}

Unlike the dude on the video, I get a message dialog with a black screen and no "Hi!".
Is there a problem with the code? Or maybe with my computer?
I would like to mention that I am having quite a hard time using Eclipse Window Builder, it keeps blocking every now and then, and I don't know if there's a problem with the Eclipse version I am using or with my computer performances.
Thanks alot!

Comment: Don't create all your code on one line. Please read a guide on Java code formatting conventions and follow them.

Comment: I fixed it for you now, but in the future, you should take responsibility for learning the rules of the language and of this site and following them.

Comment: Thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels !! I'll make sure to read the formatting code options for StackOverFlow for my next posts

Comment: Please do that, but note that your formatting problem had nothing to do with StackOverflow rules and formatting and all to do with your creating what should be 5 lines of code on a single line. That's a debugging nightmare whether it's on StackOverflow or elsewhere. As to your actual problem, you may have to post a small complete (well formatted) program for us to say what is wrong.

Comment: This could be an issue with the video card/drivers

Comment: I just added the full code. But I really think I have it has more to do with the card driver. I got it to work after restarting my computer. You think updating my graphic driver will deal with that? Or could it be a problem with the graphic card itself? (I have an Intel HD 4000 Graphics)